# Defining constructor with default values to a composition object as a private field

Tags: c++, object, composition

Thanks in advance to everyone who is trying to help.
I want to declare an empty object in the main as follows:
The object has primitive fields and composite fields, all are private.
what is the correct signature of the constructor in the *.h file?
for example if I have class Rectangle, which contains a height and width fields among 4 Points (the composition) it would be something like:

```
#include "point.h" //Standard representation of a point  
class Rectangle
{
private:
    Point bRight, bLeft, uRight, uLeft;
    double height, width;
public:  
    Rectangle(double, double, Point, Point, Point, Point)
    ... other not relevant functions  
}
```

and on the main function:

```
#include "Point.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
int main()  
{
    Rectangle r1(); //I want this row to invoke the constructor mantioned.  
                    //above without implementing an empty one.
}
```

For the primitive fields it is quiet understood, you just put default values in the signature at the *.h file.
something like:

```
Rectangle(double = 0, double = 0, Point, Point, Point, Point)
```

1. How can I put default values into the Points?
2. Not so related question: I've noticed that when I wrote in the main
   "Rectangle r1();" it compiled although I didn't assigned default values to any
   of the fields nor implemented the empty constructor, and when I debugged it the compiler wouldn't let me step into that line, why is that?

Comment: `Rectangle(double = 0, double = 0, Point = Point(), Point = Point(), Point = Point(), Point = Point())` You should really put the parameters' names in the function declaration, it improves readability.

Comment: You signature for the constructor is anyway bad, if points are given, then width and height is redundant, because 4 points are given it might not even be a rectangle at all. Rectangle classes already exist, good ones.

Comment: a rectangle only needs either 2 points or 1 point with the width and height, you can create methods to get or set all 4 points and the width and the height

Comment: Thank you first of all, but that's basically not what I'm trying to do, just wanted to get the idea of how doing it. @AlejandroDiaz, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I put default values into the Points?

You can do it as mentioned in the comment:

```
Rectangle ( double = 0, double = 0, Point = Point()
          , Point = Point(), Point = Point(), Point = Point())
```

> 2. Not so related question: I've noticed that when I wrote in the main
>      `Rectangle r1();` it compiled although I didn't assigned default values to any
>      of the fields nor implemented the empty constructor, and when I debugged it the compiler wouldn't let me step into that line, why is that?

It's not constructing an instance of `Rectangle`, but declares a function. To construct a `Rectangle` with default constructor, omit the parenthesis:

```
Rectangle r;
```

Comment: Wasn't seeing the obvious! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1) A default argument can be pretty much anything, it does not need to be a literal. Including `Point()`, as mentioned in the comments.

2) `Rectangle r1();` declares `r1` as a function taking no parameters and returning `Rectangle`. There is no initialisation there, there is no executable code there, so there is nothing to step into. There is no way to change the language so that `Rectangle r1();` declares `r1` as an object. To declare it as an object, but force it to be initialised regardless of its type, in the current standard, you can use `{}` rather than `()`. Older compilers may not support this and treat it as a syntax error.